# How to design a professional table by loading it from .csv file?

Tags: tables, multicolumn, rotating, booktabs, csvsimple

I found a similar question ([useful_question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403641/loading-data-to-fill-a-table-from-a-csv-file-with-multicolumn-header)) that I'm following to build my table but I'm not able to get the desired results, i.e. the following table but with the booktabs style (that I'm not able to reproduce in the editor used to build the table):
[image]

Here my `.csv` file (`Results_test.csv`):

```
L-point,Traj. no.,Candidate NEA (id.no. - Pdes),DVmin-TOF(km/s-day),TOFmin-DV(day-km/s),Dmin-E(km-deg),Emin-D(deg-km)
1,940,4,31,2018 PN22,5,0.495786955408242,321.691007914094,321.691007914094,0.495786955408242,1304.55816893965,0.00766274786981772,0.00766274786981772,1304.55816893965
1,940,4,40,2020 HO5,618,0.296499238470772,563.204937799172,460.61389541864,0.434673022794247,44.1321628087056,0.0043440927667307,1.06333561065898e-06,13334.9589039407
1,940,4,47,2021 GM1,207,0.321225083304834,579.001176279967,458.977213170648,0.494635569509203,272.790892644318,0.000205574640657646,8.75927739836456e-05,16162.8584126721
1,940,4,48,2021 LF6,110,0.331415081004236,547.555702810118,426.019758493117,0.494810189855507,1635.52986610854,0.00604210949390045,0.000659773039856017,15282.6573179668
2,3285,9,36,2020 CD3,188,0.441087426101912,598.687300827277,560.12998365025,0.498671715102102,226.148958936483,0.00124800816293013,4.00652387797866e-05,720.645461262528
2,3285,9,37,2020 FA1,150,0.363833486907914,617.815224738438,532.434130120624,0.477043833738971,542.710633669257,0.00217371251138835,0.000151649146744098,4570.03421246898
2,3285,9,39,2020 HF4,277,0.325869742616378,620.47407865956,495.241518020061,0.490112884848913,316.676948047764,0.00396990356158546,3.56238695777137e-05,9221.76907418505
2,3285,9,41,2020 MU1,30,0.462893611205412,597.439526870574,543.014823292621,0.496958058852358,1772.22939016773,0.00367089047771314,0.000488508198589889,13825.1797358252
2,3285,9,44,2020 WY,373,0.258567622278901,592.325909750424,457.543641043238,0.486364970362706,12.7440192334999,0.000402576106298293,5.77400555816601e-05,4916.39967823924
2,3285,9,45,2021 AK5,823,0.150275430032146,690.288217497001,553.108214337696,0.490073643361243,168.651739286611,0.000968271504982416,1.7294477167511e-05,2102.12134797594
2,3285,9,49,2021 RZ3,106,0.422216662637048,503.142619476216,412.861217455181,0.497744537876508,1010.29185702609,0.00513171449630041,3.17739132722177e-05,15816.5130302721
2,3285,9,50,2021 RG12,1161,0.0600534121618513,469.018823203997,310.079915873532,0.48383013103322,24.9984223871349,0.000221411870262754,3.9138194517227e-06,1211.60680842878
2,3285,9,52,2021 VX22,177,0.428923740467692,370.203538028964,346.732351012621,0.496774800147814,155.225383516442,9.50215401351551e-05,9.50215401351551e-05,155.225383516442
```

Here is my attempt of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht!]
        \caption{test}
        % \centering\tiny\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4} 
        \csvloop{file=Chapter_6/tables/Results_test.csv, no head, 
            before reading=\centering%\sisetup{table-number-alignment=center}
            ,
            tabular={c@{}*8{S[table-format=1.4]}S[table-format=2.4]},
            table head=\toprule & \textbf{L-point} & \textbf{Tot. no. sol.} & \textbf{Accesible NEA} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{NEA name}} & \textbf{No. sol.} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{DeltaV}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{TOF}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{dist}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{err om}}\\
            \cmidrule(lr){1-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-10}, command=&\csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii & \csvcoliv & \csvcolv & \csvcolvi & \csvcolvii & \csvcolviii & \csvcolix & \csvcolxi & \csvcolxii & \csvcolxiii & \csvcolxiv, table foot=\bottomrule}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result I get is bad and in addition I need to rotate the table by 90 deg to fit it to the page:
[image: draft result]

Can you help me to get the desired result?

EDIT: I managed to get the desidered table but I need some adjustments, i.e. a better vertical alignment of the 2nd column `Candidate NEA (id. – Pdes)`, and a better vertical alignment of the successive columns with respect to the `\cmidrule` lines.
Here is my new code:

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
    \begin{tabular}{
    c %col1 L-point
    S[table-format=4.0] %col2 No. of. sol.
    S[table-format=0.5,input-decimal-markers=-,output-decimal-marker=-] %col3 Cand. NEA
    S[table-format=1.3,round-mode=places,round-precision=3] %col4
    S[table-format=3.0,round-mode=figures,round-precision=3] %col5
    S[table-format=3.0,round-mode=figures,round-precision=3] %col6
    S[table-format=1.3,round-mode=figures,round-precision=3] %col7
    S[table-format=4.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col8
    S[table-format=1.2e1,scientific-notation = true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2] %col9
    S[table-format=1.2e1,scientific-notation = true,round-mode=places,round-precision=2] %col10
    S[table-format=6.0,round-mode=places,round-precision=0] %col11
   }
    \toprule
    \textbf{L} & \multicolumn{1}{M{1cm}}{\textbf{No.of\newline sol.}} & \multicolumn{1}{M{3cm}}{\textbf{Candidate NEA  (id. \mbox{--} Pdes)}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{2.5cm}}{\textbf{$\boldsymbol{\Delta V_{min}\mbox{--}TOF}$ (km/s \mbox{--} day)}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{2.5cm}}{\textbf{$\boldsymbol{TOF_{min}-\Delta V}$ (day \mbox{--} km/s)}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{3cm}}{\textbf{$\boldsymbol{d_{min}\mbox{--}E}$\newline (km \mbox{--} deg)}} & \multicolumn{2}{M{3cm}}{\textbf{$\boldsymbol{E_{min} \mbox{--} d}$\newline (deg\mbox{--}km)}} \\ 
    \cmidrule(){1-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}
     & 5 & 31 - 2018 PN22 & 0.495786955408242 & 321.691007914094 & 321.691007914094 & 0.495786955408242 & 1304.55816893965 & 0.00766274786981772 & 0.00766274786981772 & 1304.55816893965 \\
     & 618 & 40 - 2020 HO5 & 0.296499238470772 & 563.204937799172 & 460.61389541864 & 0.434673022794247 & 44.1321628087056 & 0.0043440927667307 & 1.06333561065898e-06 & 13334.9589039407 \\
     & 207 & 47 - 2021 GM1 & 0.321225083304834 & 579.001176279967 & 458.977213170648 & 0.494635569509203 & 272.790892644318 & 0.000205574640657646 & 8.75927739836456e-05 & 16162.8584126721 \\
    \multirow{-4}{*}{\num{1}} & 110 & 48 - 2021 LF6 & 0.331415081004236 & 547.555702810118 & 426.019758493117 & 0.494810189855507 & 1635.52986610854 & 0.00604210949390045 & 0.000659773039856017 &     15282.6573179668 \\ \midrule
     & 188 & 36 - 2020 CD3 & 0.441087426101912 & 598.687300827277 & 560.12998365025 & 0.498671715102102 & 226.148958936483 & 0.00124800816293013 & 4.00652387797866e-05 & 720.645461262528 \\
     & 150 & 37 - 2020 FA1 & 0.363833486907914 & 617.815224738438 & 532.434130120624 & 0.477043833738971 & 542.710633669257 & 0.00217371251138835 & 0.000151649146744098 & 4570.03421246898 \\
     & 277 & 39 - 2020 HF4 & 0.325869742616378 & 620.47407865956 & 495.241518020061 & 0.490112884848913 & 316.676948047764 & 0.00396990356158546 & 3.56238695777137e-05 & 9221.76907418505 \\
     & 30 & 41 - 2020 MU1 & 0.462893611205412 & 597.439526870574 & 543.014823292621 & 0.496958058852358 & 1772.22939016773 & 0.00367089047771314 & 0.000488508198589889 & 13825.1797358252 \\
     & 373 & 44 - 2020 WY & 0.258567622278901 & 592.325909750424 & 457.543641043238 & 0.486364970362706 & 12.7440192334999 & 0.000402576106298293 & 5.77400555816601e-05 & 4916.39967823924 \\
     & 823 & 45 - 2021 AK5 & 0.150275430032146 & 690.288217497001 & 553.108214337696 & 0.490073643361243 & 168.651739286611 & 0.000968271504982416 & 1.7294477167511e-05 & 2102.12134797594 \\
     & 106 & 49 - 2021 RZ3 & 0.422216662637048 & 503.142619476216 & 412.861217455181 & 0.497744537876508 & 1010.29185702609 & 0.00513171449630041 & 3.17739132722177e-05 & 15816.5130302721 \\
     & 1161 & 50 - 2021 RG12 & 0.0600534121618513 & 469.018823203997 & 310.079915873532 & 0.48383013103322 & 24.9984223871349 & 0.000221411870262754 & 3.9138194517227e-06 & 1211.60680842878 \\
    \multirow{-9}{*}{\num{2}} & 177 & 52 - 2021 VX22 & 0.428923740467692 & 370.203538028964 & 346.732351012621 & 0.496774800147814 & 155.225383516442 & 9.50215401351551e-05 & 9.50215401351551e-05 &     155.225383516442 \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
    \end{table}
```

The result is shown in the following image and I have indicated with red arrows the adjustments I need, i.e. the column or text to shift according arrow verse.
[image: table to be refined]

Comment: I would first manually type the first two or three rows and then see if your commands for the table work without calling for an external file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My personal recommendation is that you use already available tools instead of creating your own. Such as https://www.tablesgenerator.com/.

First your .csv is all different for the format you want to achieve. You have a Candidate Column distributed among three other rows so using Excel concatenation you can easily fix that. Then just specify by columns which format type you want by adjusting the number of digits or selecting Scientific  format.

Thus the correct `.csv` should look like this:

```
 L-point,Traj. no.,Candidate NEA (id.no. - Pdes),DVmin-TOF(km/s-day),,TOFmin-DV (day-km/s),,Dmin-E (km-deg),,Emin-D(deg-km),
1,5,31 - 2018 PN22 5,0.496,322,322,0.496,1305,7.66E-03,7.66E-03,1305
1,618,40 - 2020 HO5 618,0.296,563,461,0.435,44,4.34E-03,1.06E-06,13335
1,207,47 - 2021 GM1 207,0.321,579,459,0.495,273,2.06E-04,8.76E-05,16163
1,110,48 - 2021 LF6 110,0.331,548,426,0.495,1636,6.04E-03,6.60E-04,15283
2,188,36 - 2020 CD3 188,0.441,599,560,0.499,226,1.25E-03,4.01E-05,721
2,150,37 - 2020 FA1 150,0.364,618,532,0.477,543,2.17E-03,1.52E-04,4570
2,277,39 - 2020 HF4 277,0.326,620,495,0.490,317,3.97E-03,3.56E-05,9222
2,30,41 - 2020 MU1 30,0.463,597,543,0.497,1772,3.67E-03,4.89E-04,13825
2,373,44 - 2020 WY 373,0.259,592,458,0.486,13,4.03E-04,5.77E-05,4916
2,823,45 - 2021 AK5 823,0.150,690,553,0.490,169,9.68E-04,1.73E-05,2102
2,106,49 - 2021 RZ3 106,0.422,503,413,0.498,1010,5.13E-03,3.18E-05,15817
2,1161,50 - 2021 RG12 1161,0.060,469,310,0.484,25,2.21E-04,3.91E-06,1212
2,177,52 - 2021 VX22 177,0.429,370,347,0.497,155,9.50E-05,9.50E-05,155
```

The next step is simply copy-paste (from EXCEL not the .csv) into the tables generator website. Merge the columns and rows you want. Select the cells you want different color text and finally choose Booktabs table style in the dropdown menu. You can even specify directly which borders are to be drawn and it automatically detects where it should use `\toprule , \midrule , \cmidrule` etc.

The site generate button generates the code and then you only need to perform minor adjustments if any.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\author{michel.gordillo }


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
\toprule
L-point & Traj. no. & Candidate NEA (id.no. - Pdes) & \multicolumn{2}{c}{DVmin-TOF(km/s-day)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{TOFmin-DV (day-km/s)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Dmin-E (km-deg)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Emin-D(deg-km)} \\ 
\cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}
 & 5 & 31 - 2018 PN22 5 & 0.496 & 322 & 322 & 0.496 & 1305 & 7.66E-03 & 7.66E-03 & 1305 \\
 & 618 & 40 - 2020 HO5 618 & 0.296 & 563 & 461 & 0.435 & 44 & 4.34E-03 & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} 1.06E-06} & 13335 \\
 & 207 & 47 - 2021 GM1 207 & 0.321 & 579 & 459 & 0.495 & 273 & 2.06E-04 & 8.76E-05 & 16163 \\
\multirow{-4}{*}{1} & 110 & 48 - 2021 LF6 110 & 0.331 & 548 & 426 & 0.495 & 1636 & 6.04E-03 & 6.60E-04 & 15283 \\ \midrule
 & 188 & 36 - 2020 CD3 188 & 0.441 & 599 & 560 & 0.499 & 226 & 1.25E-03 & 4.01E-05 & 721 \\
 & 150 & 37 - 2020 FA1 150 & 0.364 & 618 & 532 & 0.477 & 543 & 2.17E-03 & 1.52E-04 & 4570 \\
 & 277 & 39 - 2020 HF4 277 & 0.326 & 620 & 495 & 0.490 & 317 & 3.97E-03 & 3.56E-05 & 9222 \\
 & 30 & 41 - 2020 MU1 30 & 0.463 & 597 & 543 & 0.497 & 1772 & 3.67E-03 & 4.89E-04 & 13825 \\
 & 373 & 44 - 2020 WY 373 & 0.259 & 592 & 458 & 0.486 & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} 13} & 4.03E-04 & 5.77E-05 & 4916 \\
 & 823 & 45 - 2021 AK5 823 & 0.150 & 690 & 553 & 0.490 & 169 & 9.68E-04 & 1.73E-05 & 2102 \\
 & 106 & 49 - 2021 RZ3 106 & 0.422 & 503 & 413 & 0.498 & 1010 & 5.13E-03 & 3.18E-05 & 15817 \\
 & 1161 & 50 - 2021 RG12 1161 & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} 0.060} & 469 & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} 310} & 0.484 & 25 & 2.21E-04 & 3.91E-06 & 1212 \\
\multirow{-9}{*}{2} & 177 & 52 - 2021 VX22 177 & 0.429 & 370 & 347 & 0.497 & 155 & 9.50E-05 & 9.50E-05 & 155\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Resulting table:

[image: bookmarktable-multirow-multicol-xcolor]

It is far better to have the code generated in this way as it is easier to modify for details. As usually tables are very non general in terms of formatting. For example you would want to change your headers into the math-mode which I'm assuming you already know how to do. If you need to reduce the columns width so the headers are split into two lines I recommend the array package: It has the commands:

- `p{'width'}` paragraph column with text vertically aligned at the top
- `m{'width'}`    paragraph column with text vertically aligned in the
  middle (requires array package)
- `b{'width'}` paragraph column with text
  vertically aligned at the bottom (requires array package) [source](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables)

Finally the code for this table:

```
%remember to include the array package    
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccc}
    \toprule
    L-point & Traj. no. & \multicolumn{1}{m{3cm}}{Candidate NEA (id.no. - Pdes)} & \multicolumn{2}{m{3cm}}{DVmin-TOF (km/s-day)} & \multicolumn{2}{m{2.5cm}}{TOFmin-DV (day-km/s)} & \multicolumn{2}{m{3cm}}{Dmin-E (km-deg)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Emin-D (deg-km)} \\ 
    \cmidrule(r){1-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-9}\cmidrule(l){10-11}
     & 5 & 31 - 2018 PN22 5 & 0.496 & 322 & 322 & 0.496 & 1305 & 7.66E-03 & 7.66E-03 & 1305 \\
     & 618 & 40 - 2020 HO5 618 & 0.296 & 563 & 461 & 0.435 & 44 & 4.34E-03 & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} 1.06E-06} & 13335 \\
     & 207 & 47 - 2021 GM1 207 & 0.321 & 579 & 459 & 0.495 & 273 & 2.06E-04 & 8.76E-05 & 16163 \\
    \multirow{-4}{*}{1} & 110 & 48 - 2021 LF6 110 & 0.331 & 548 & 426 & 0.495 & 1636 & 6.04E-03 & 6.60E-04 & 15283 \\ \midrule
     & 188 & 36 - 2020 CD3 188 & 0.441 & 599 & 560 & 0.499 & 226 & 1.25E-03 & 4.01E-05 & 721 \\
     & 150 & 37 - 2020 FA1 150 & 0.364 & 618 & 532 & 0.477 & 543 & 2.17E-03 & 1.52E-04 & 4570 \\
     & 277 & 39 - 2020 HF4 277 & 0.326 & 620 & 495 & 0.490 & 317 & 3.97E-03 & 3.56E-05 & 9222 \\
     & 30 & 41 - 2020 MU1 30 & 0.463 & 597 & 543 & 0.497 & 1772 & 3.67E-03 & 4.89E-04 & 13825 \\
     & 373 & 44 - 2020 WY 373 & 0.259 & 592 & 458 & 0.486 & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} 13} & 4.03E-04 & 5.77E-05 & 4916 \\
     & 823 & 45 - 2021 AK5 823 & 0.150 & 690 & 553 & 0.490 & 169 & 9.68E-04 & 1.73E-05 & 2102 \\
     & 106 & 49 - 2021 RZ3 106 & 0.422 & 503 & 413 & 0.498 & 1010 & 5.13E-03 & 3.18E-05 & 15817 \\
     & 1161 & 50 - 2021 RG12 1161 & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} 0.060} & 469 & {\color[HTML]{FE0000} 310} & 0.484 & 25 & 2.21E-04 & 3.91E-06 & 1212 \\
    \multirow{-9}{*}{2} & 177 & 52 - 2021 VX22 177 & 0.429 & 370 & 347 & 0.497 & 155 & 9.50E-05 & 9.50E-05 & 155\\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
    }
    \caption{}
    \label{tab:my-table}
    \end{table}
```

[image: Booktables plus array package]

Comment: Thank you @Michel, great work! Only one thing: can you show how to align at center of the cell the header  `DVmin-TOF (km/s-day)`?

Comment: You're welcome! I believe the easiest thing to do is just define a new column type in the preamble:

`\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}`

Then simply use our new column type _M_ instead of _m_ in the `\multicolumn{2}{M{3cm}}{DVmin-TOF (km/s-day)}`

Comment: Hi @Michel, thank you again for your valuable suggestions. I need a final touch to get the final result and for this purpose I updated my question, can you help me about the correct alignment of the column and text I indicated in my updated question?

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what is it you actually want to adjust. From what I understand you just want to modify the alignment?

There's additional options in siunitx you can add to the S type column.

'S[table-format=0.5,input-decimal-markers=-,output-decimal-marker=-,table-number-alignment = left] %col3 Cand. NEA'

`table-number-alignment = right` and `table-number-alignment = center` are also available options.

Comment: For the titles you can define whatever style of column you desire really in the same manner we previously defined the M columntype : 

Look at this answer for example:
`\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}` is just an example (I suggest you occupy another letter as M is apparently already in use by siunitx).

`\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}   %% centered`

`\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{#1}}  %% right aligned`

Comment: Some other examples: [source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154958/vertically-centered-and-right-left-center-horizontal-alignment-in-tabular)

Comment: I want to better center the headers and the numbers in their respective columns by shifting them according the verse indicated by the arrows. The problem of the headers is when I go to the newline by using `\newline`, in this case I get a blank space on the right that i want to remove in order to vertically center the two lines of header.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140245/discussion-between-giuseppe-and-michel).